# how can I send selected UIButton's value to server

Tags: swift, database-connection

I am using swift 3.0 and I want to connect registration page of my application to php server

Now I can't able to store gender(male/female) button value, I want to store value of selected button to the server through my swift code, Below is my code of "POST" method
(I have written it inside button action)

right now I am getting false value for gender buttons into my database

Can anybody help me?

```
   @IBAction func submitBtnAction(_ sender: Any)
{
    let desi = self.designation.text;
    let descri = self.desc.text;
    let expfrom = self.expFrom.text;
    let expto = self.expTo.text;
    let education = self.edu.text;
    let skill = self.skills.text;
    let salaryfrom = self.salaryFrom.text;
    let salaryto = self.salaryTo.text;
    let genderMale = self.maleBtn.isSelected;
    let genderFemale = self.femaleBtn.isSelected;
    let loc = self.location.text;
    let vacancy = self.vacancies.text;
    let interviewfrom = self.interviewDateFrom.text;
    let interviewto = self.interviewDateTo.text;

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://172.16.1.55/Employee_API/v1/emp_register.php")! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "emp_desig=\(desi!)&emp_job_desc=\(descri!)&emp_exp_from=\(expfrom!)&emp_exp_to=\(expto!)&emp_edu_qual=\(education!)&emp_skills=\(skill!)&emp_salary_from=\(salaryfrom!)&emp_salary_to=\(salaryto!)&emp_gender=\(genderMale)&emp_location=\(loc!)&emp_vacancy=\(vacancy!)&emp_intv_from=\(interviewfrom!)&emp_intv_to=\(interviewto!)"

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(error.debugDescription)")
            return
        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print(responseString!)
    }
        task.resume()
}
```

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: You aren't fully explaining your situation.  Help you with what?  What does the response string say?  Or does it return anything?

Comment: I had written over there that right now I am getting false value even if I have selected male button from my application still am getting false value **I want selected buttons value (either male or female)**

Comment: As I set textfield's input value (let desi = self.designation.text;) like this I am getting values for all fields except male/female button, what should I send in my request to get buttons value?

Answer (score 0):

the method isSelected returns a bool value, not the button text. For that you can use something like this

```
let genderMale = self.maleBtn.isSelected ? "male":""
let genderFemale = self.femaleBtn.isSelected ? "female":""
```

edit:

When you select the gender, tapping the button, in that moment the isSelected method will return true, but when you tap on other element, the button turns deselected and the isSelected method returns false

You have to implements buttons actions to set the value on a variable